# Wmi. При запуске программы появляется окно выбора msi-библиотнеи

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, wmi

Всем привет!

Пишу первую программу с WMI на Delphi Embarcadero XE3. Добавил ISWbemLocator, просит ввести сервер, ввожу root\COMV2, ошибка. Когда пытаюсь создать этот объект динамически - появляется окно поиска некой msi-файла. Как победить?

Разжуйте идиоту на идиотский язык, а то у меня уже остатки мозга закипают...

PS: для примера как я создаю динамически этот объект...

```
type 
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Services: ISWbemServices;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var Locator: ISWbemLocator;
begin
  Locator := CoSWbemLocator.Create;
  Services := Locator.ConnectServer('.', 'root\cimv2', '', '', '', '', 0, nil)
end;

end.
```

[image: Сообщение, которое выдает система]

Comment: Сообщение и имя файла приложите.

Comment: Добавил скрин сообщения, которое выводит программа

Comment: wbemtest нормально работает?

Comment: А что это? и с чем его едят? Просто я с wmi сталкиваюсь впервые, да и на Embarcadero перебрался всего недели 2-3 назад (До этого работал только под 7 делфой)

Comment: это такая утилита с GUI, которая умеет создавать на заказ нужные объекты WMI и делать запросы на WQL.
Запускается просто - через Пуск -> Выполнить.

Comment: понял. А какую актуальную литературу/статьи/блог можете посоветовать для начинающих в wmi?

Comment: лучший источник - MSDN.

Comment: А именно для delphi? А то читаю статьи, а они старые и то ли примеры устарели, то ли это я такой д***к, но как не работает...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41947/discussion-between-gbg-and-garmayev).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день!

Попробуйте вместо *CoSWbemLocator* использовать *SWbemLocator*,
а также генератор кода для delphi с использованием классов WMI
https://theroadtodelphi.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/